# Need to get links from youtube video page, links are loading through javascript. Using python request module

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I need to read links of videos from below links.

```
https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCoq5eKuZhG7Dm-63YFUYQog/videos
```

The links which are loading at the start are easy to get but those are loading after javascript are difficult. Can anyone help me to identify how to get those using Python request module.
I do not understand what would be the Post request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the official API which is straightforward to search for the videos for a specific channel :

- Go to [Google Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com/), search Youtube Data API / enable Youtube Data API v3

[image: enable API screen]

- Go to Credentials / Create Credentials / API key

[image: API key screen]

- install google api client for python :

  ```
  pip3 install --upgrade google-api-python-client
  ```

Use the API key in the script below. This script fetch videos items from channel with id `UCoq5eKuZhG7Dm-63YFUYQog`, use [pagination](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/blob/master/docs/pagination.md#pagination) to get all of them, and re-create the link from the videoId :

```
import googleapiclient.discovery
from urllib.parse import parse_qs, urlparse
import re

#extract channel id from url
url = 'https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCoq5eKuZhG7Dm-63YFUYQog/videos'
channel_id = re.search('channel\/(.*)\/videos', url).group(1)

print(f'get all videos links from {channel_id}')
youtube = googleapiclient.discovery.build("youtube", "v3", developerKey = "YOUR_KEY")

request = youtube.search().list(
    channelId = channel_id,
    part = "id",
    maxResults = 50,
    type = "video"
)
response = request.execute()

videos_items = []
while request is not None:
    response = request.execute()
    videos_items += response["items"]
    request = youtube.search().list_next(request, response)

print(f"total: {len(videos_items)}")
print([ 
    f'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={t["id"]["videoId"]}'
    for t in videos_items
])
```

Output:

```
get all videos links from UCoq5eKuZhG7Dm-63YFUYQog
total: 80
[
    'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uORsR14S7gw', 
    'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cARHPeZIUs4', 
    ............
    'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CF2JO5a2EHE', 
    'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1yLesOxlHs0'
]
```

If you need more details about the video, use `part = "snippet"`, see [this](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use request smodule only. You would have to scrape website for those links with Selenium and / or BeautifulSoup. There is plenty of help here about those .

Here is a link to one of my answers which will give you a head start.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/62480188/13775029

You'll have to search for different div and possibly  tags .

Comment: But can I do it on linux?

Comment: Sure, but in GUI or shell only ?

Comment: Only shell, is that possible?